# cleaner html code from tex4ht

Tags: tables, tex4ht, cleanup

I wish to have cleaner html code from tex4ht, but I am not able to see, form the code from the file,  why there are carriage returns in the html code

this is the code for `tabular`. I added several `HCode{\Hnewline}`, in order to have a better view:

```
\Configure{tabular}
      {\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP \halignTB{tabular}\putVBorder }
      {\HCode{</table>}\HCode{\Hnewline}}
      {\HCode{<tr \Hnewline}\halignTR
                            \HCode{ id="TBL-\TableNo-\HRow-">}\HCode{\Hnewline}}
      {\r:HA\HCode{\Hnewline}}
      {\HCode{\Hnewline}\HCode{<td \ifnum \HMultispan>1 colspan="\HMultispan"\fi}%
         \halignTD \HCode{ id="TBL-\TableNo-\HRow-\HCol"
         \Hnewline class="td}\NoFonts
           \bgroup
              \ifx \ttfamily\:UnDef \else \ttfamily\fi
              \ColMargins
           \egroup
\EndNoFonts
```

for instance, a table like this

```
\begin{tabular} {c c}
AAA & QQQ  \tabularnewline
WWW & SSS
\end{tabular}
```

produces something ugly with breakings of line everywhere:

```
<div class="tabular"><table id="TBL-1" class="tabular" 
cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"  
><colgroup id="TBL-1-1g"><col 
id="TBL-1-1" /><col 
id="TBL-1-2" /></colgroup><tr  
 style="vertical-align:baseline;" id="TBL-1-1-"> 

<td  style="white-space:nowrap; text-align:center;" id="TBL-1-1-1"  
class="td11"> <span 
class="cmr-12">AAA </span></td> 
<td  style="white-space:nowrap; text-align:center;" id="TBL-1-1-2"  
class="td11"> <span 
class="cmr-12">QQQ  </span></td>
</tr> 
<tr  
 style="vertical-align:baseline;" id="TBL-1-2-"> 

<td  style="white-space:nowrap; text-align:center;" id="TBL-1-2-1"  
class="td11"> <span 
class="cmr-12">WWW </span></td> 
<td  style="white-space:nowrap; text-align:center;" id="TBL-1-2-2"  
class="td11">  <span 
class="cmr-12">SSS   </span></td>
</tr> 
</table> 

</div>
```

is it possible to have something nicer in avoiding the carriage returns, for instance at the beginning:

```
<div class="tabular"><table id="TBL-1" class="tabular"  cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<colgroup id="TBL-1-1g">
<col id="TBL-1-1" /><col id="TBL-1-2" /></colgroup>
<tr  style="vertical-align:baseline;" id="TBL-1-1-">
```

which means keeping as many environment `< XXX>`, like `<table id="TBL-1", .....>` on one line, with each new beginning/closing of an environment appearing on a new line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You insert lots of newlines in your configuration with `\HCode{\Hnewline}`. Just put them only in places where you really want them:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{tabular}
      {\ifvmode \IgnorePar\fi \EndP \halignTB{tabular}\putVBorder }
      {\HCode{\Hnewline</table>}}
      {\HCode{\Hnewline<tr }\halignTR    \HCode{ id="TBL-\TableNo-\HRow-">}\HCode{}}
      {\HCode{</tr>}}
      {\HCode{}\HCode{<td \ifnum \HMultispan>1 colspan="\HMultispan"\fi}%
         \halignTD \HCode{ id="TBL-\TableNo-\HRow-\HCol"
         class="td}\NoFonts
           \bgroup
              \ifx \ttfamily\:UnDef \else \ttfamily\fi
              \ColMargins
           \egroup
\EndNoFonts \HCode{">}}{\HCode{</td>}}
\begin{document}

\EndPreamble
```

produces:

```html
<div class="tabular"> <table id="TBL-1" class="tabular" 
cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"  
><colgroup id="TBL-1-1g"><col 
id="TBL-1-1" /><col 
id="TBL-1-2" /></colgroup> 
<tr  style="vertical-align:baseline;" id="TBL-1-1-"><td  style="white-space:nowrap; text-align:center;" id="TBL-1-1-1" class="td11"> AAA </td><td  style="white-space:nowrap; text-align:center;" id="TBL-1-1-2" class="td11">QQQ</td></tr> 
<tr  style="vertical-align:baseline;" id="TBL-1-2-"><td  style="white-space:nowrap; text-align:center;" id="TBL-1-2-1" class="td11">WWW</td> <td  style="white-space:nowrap; text-align:center;" id="TBL-1-2-2" class="td11"> SSS</td> </tr> 
</table>
</div>
```